# Cannot remove external testers in iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, testflight

I have a problem with iTunes Connect TestFlight where I cannot see Internal Testers in the list any more. I did some research and found out if they are also External Testers, I have to delete them.

BUT now I cannot even delete them from External Testers list. I selected and clicked delete but their emails were still there, without any error.

Anyone has this issue and how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems to work again. Yesterday, I couldn't remove my readers from the external tester list, but now it miraculously worked. The only thing I did is create a group and add one of the users to it. Then I could remove all testers from the external list, not just the one added to the group.

Comment: Yeah it works again for me too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a known bug in Itunes Connect. I called Apple Developer Support and they said they are aware of the issue and "working on a fix". Which is awesome because apparently this has been going on for over a week.

Comment: This was resolved back in October, so if you are seeing this now it's likely a new issue and you might want to check with Apple yourself.

Comment: Apple always say like this and this bug exists until now

Comment: I confirm the bug still exist to this day (14/10/2016)

Comment: I can confirm that this is STILL an issue (07/03/2017)

Comment: Still an issue! (28.11.2017)