# Remove testflight internal tester and external tester

Tags: app-store-connect

I am trying to remove both internal and external tester, I removed some email id of theirs and also totally delete but still, that tester can get the invitation.

So this is the bug or something I missed out.

Comment: Can you provide instructions for how to replicate the issue?  If not, this would be as you said a bug, in which case there is no question.  Bugs should be reported to Apple.

Comment: Yes, I did remove email ID from internal/external tester. I can not attach the screenshort becuase I does not have enough review. but you can check the answer given bellow by Ram. I did same

Answer (score 0):

There are two options appears before deleting from the test flight, you should choose "Delete these testers from TestFlight" and it will remove selected email id's to permanently delete. Other one option will delete only from the specific group.

Again it will happen, try to create the new group with new testers.

also, refer this - [Cannot remove external testers in iTunes Connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33071471/cannot-remove-external-testers-in-itunes-connect)

[image]

Comment: Yes I did same,but still getting inviation.

Comment: then it is the serious issue, you have to ask Apple, It's working me fine